# Got this error when implementing Firebase chat application from the given link

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the [link](http://myapptemplates.com/simple-android-chat-app-tutorial-firebase-integration/) from where I am implementing a chat application :-

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.chatt.demo.model.Conversation is missing a constructor with no arguments
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix$zza.zzaC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzd(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaix.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.chatt.demo.Chat$2.onDataChange(Chat.java:195)
>                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzafp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagp.zzSu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzags$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Have you followed up on what the error says? "Conversation is missing a constructor with no arguments"

Answer (score 0):

When using `getValue` as below, your `Conversation` class needs (as per documentation) to have default no argument constructor for json deserialization to work.

```
Conversation conversation = ds.getValue(Conversation.class);
```